# does the database provider analyse and "complie" Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, .net

We know that a LINQ to SQL query is not executed inside your C# program. Instead, it is translated into SQL, sent across a wire, and executed on a database server. Let's say we have the following LINQ Query

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            where c.City == "Nantes"
            select new { c.City, c.CompanyName };
```

It is first translated into the following SQL statement and then executed on a database server:

```
SELECT [t0].[City], [t0].[CompanyName]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[City] = @p0
```

My question is, why not let the compiler directly compile LINQ Query into SQL, why convert LINQ query into a Expression tree first then "compile" this Expression tree into SQL, which adds an extra layer?

I understand the there is other database technologies such as no sql etc, so we can't let the C# complier to handle every different technologies, so does it mean that it is the database provider such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer will analyse Expression Tree and turn it into SQL, which means that it is the database provider that handle Expression Tree?

Comment: LINQ queries are *made* of expressions, they don't get compiled/translated to expressions. `where c.City == "Nantes"` or the equivalent `.Where(c=> c.City == "Nantes")` use expressions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your answer. So does the database provider such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer translate expressions to SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Expression tree is a kind of AST (Abstract syntax tree) which needs to be processed by the "provider" like SQL Server or PostgreSQL or NoSQL, or even XML.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when you say "processed by the "provider" like SQL Server", do you mean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer that installed on client's side or SQL Server on server's side?

Comment: Yes, I meant Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgSQL, MongoDriver etc